# How to set element value and run function on load Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to refactor a small Javascript function that simply adds an `active` class to the parent `<div>` of a series of radio buttons on page load as well as via a change.

My function is:

```js
function toggleActiveState (event) {
  const el = event.target
  const parent = el.closest('[data-toggle-has-btn-group]')
  const buttons = parent.getElementsByClassName('js__btn-toggle')

  var i
  for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].classList.remove('active')
  }

  el.parentElement.classList.add('active')
}
```

My markup is:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="btn-group-toggle d-flex flex-row" data-toggle="buttons" data-toggle-has-btn-group>
    <label class="btn btn-custom btn-outline-primary btn-sm active flex-fill mr-1 js__btn-toggle">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" value="Mr" checked onclick="toggleActiveState(event)"> Mr
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-custom btn-outline-primary btn-sm flex-fill mx-1 js__btn-toggle">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" value="Mrs" onclick="toggleActiveState(event)"> Mrs
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-custom btn-outline-primary btn-sm flex-fill mx-1 js__btn-toggle">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" value="Miss" onclick="toggleActiveState(event)"> Miss
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-custom btn-outline-primary btn-sm flex-fill ml-1 js__btn-toggle">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" value="Other" onclick="toggleActiveState(event)"> Other
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

When clicking a radio button, the `toggleActiveState(event)` runs and I'm able to remove the active classes and add a class to the input I clicked.

I have multiple of these `.btn-group-toggle` elements on the page.

What I need to do is be able to set the active class state of say the **Mrs** element on page load and it's value by calling my function like so:

`toggleActiveState('options', 'Mrs')` and then this would be active, and selected...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event listener on window load and add the class there. Like I've done below  based on your code.

```js
function toggleActiveState (event) {
  const el = event.target
  const parent = el.closest('[data-toggle-has-btn-group]')
  const buttons = parent.getElementsByClassName('js__btn-toggle')

  var i
  for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].classList.remove('active')
  }

  el.parentElement.classList.add('active')
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
   const checkedInput = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked');
   checkedInput.parentElement.classList.add('active');
})
```

```css
.active {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="btn-group-toggle d-flex flex-row" data-toggle="buttons" data-toggle-has-btn-group>
    <label class="btn btn-custom btn-outline-primary btn-sm flex-fill mr-1 js__btn-toggle">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" value="Mr" checked onclick="toggleActiveState(event)"> Mr
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-custom btn-outline-primary btn-sm flex-fill mx-1 js__btn-toggle">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" value="Mrs" onclick="toggleActiveState(event)"> Mrs
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-custom btn-outline-primary btn-sm flex-fill mx-1 js__btn-toggle">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" value="Miss" onclick="toggleActiveState(event)"> Miss
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-custom btn-outline-primary btn-sm flex-fill ml-1 js__btn-toggle">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" value="Other" onclick="toggleActiveState(event)"> Other
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! I completely forgot about this, it worked :)